# I have 30 docx file with the different name in that I want to to replace the some letters without affecting the inside content how do I that?

Tags: java

Like I am having
Req_250: a
Req_6497: b
Sysreq_234 a
Here I want to put-> "COLON" instead of ":" and "_" instead of " "
How to that please give idea

Answer (score 1):

You can used `File renameTo()` to rename your file

such as

```
File file=new File("../path/Req_250: a Req_6497: b Sysreq_234.docx");
boolean renameResult = file.renameTo(new File(file.getParent()+"/"+file.getName().replace(":", "COLON").replace(" ", "_")));
```